# JQuery mobile how to put a pic inside data-role="header"

Tags: mobile, header

I want to put a image on header in jQuery mobile.

I try this, but it doesn't work at all.

```
<div data-role="header">
    <img src = "hello.png">
    <h1>welcome</h1>
</div>
```

but strange is that the image did not show in Header.

The pic appears before the header.

But I want the pic inside the header

Answer (score 0):

on one here.
I find the problem it seems that you should put the  element in the tag

```
<h1><image src="a.png"></h1>
```

and it works